# No route matches [DELETE] "/tags"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Edited to include config/routes.rb file.**

I'm working through the Jumpstartlab Blogger 2 tutorial and I've run into trouble trying to delete tags from a tag list. This is my first Rails project and I'm still trying to wrap my head around MVC and routing.

Here's the code from my Tags view:

```
<h1>All Tags</h1>

<ul id="tags">
  <% @tags.each do |tag| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag), class: 'tag_name' %>
    <%= link_to "Delete", tags_path(@tag), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Really delete the tag?"} %>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

And the code from my Tags controller:

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @tags = Tag.all
  end

  def destroy
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
    @tag.destroy
  end

end
```

And config.routes.rb:

```
Blogger::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'articles#index'
  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
  resources :tags

end
```

The error I'm getting is **No route matches [DELETE] "/tags"**.

I feel like the issue is something basic that I haven't quite grasped yet. I would really appreciate if someone could help me understand what I've missed and how it works. If I haven't provided enough information, please let me know. And thanks!

Comment: Can you add your `config/routes.rb` file?

Comment: Added config/routes.rb file.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the DELETE route is based on an instance (just 1 tag) of a resource, not the collection (the group of tags).

So you have to change this line:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", tags_path(@tag), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Really delete the tag?"} %>
```

To use `tag_path(tag)`:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", tag_path(tag), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Really delete the tag?"} %>
```

Comment: When I change the route to tag_path(tag) and try deleting, I get a different error: SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DELETE FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."id" = ?.

Comment: Seems like you have some validation that is failing when you destroy. Can you please post your `tag.rb` file?

Comment: Laith, he does not have the validation, actually. If he had, he would get validation error, not database error. He has constraint in db, but have not matching validator in model. So, `tag.rb` is irrelevant, what would be nice to see is `schema.rb`, particularly `tags` table definition.

Comment: Appreciate the help but most of this is over my head. I'm going to go through the exercise again on the weekend and try to improve my understanding of how everything fits together. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the issue (it was in the `tag.rb` file). Tag has a `has_many` relationship to `Taggings` so I added `:dependent => :destroy` and it worked.